# How to run Java in Notepad++ command window to accept input

Tags: java, notepad++, command-line

I'm don't know how to use the command line with Notepad++ to accept input and display output.

Comment: Are trying to **run** or **compile** a java program from within Notepad++?

Comment: @heavyd - sounds like he has a console interface with his program, and wants to use it from notepad++. Can't be sure, though. @Ian, please add details to your question about it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [NppExec](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/) plugin.  It allows for using the command prompt and Command line programs.  There is also a [nice guide](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Compiling_Source_Code) for setting up compilers.